# What will be the security risks if we persist "e" as part of schnorr signature=(r,s,e) and extract publicKey from signature at verification

Tags: multi-signature, public-key, secp256k1, schnorr-signatures

We know unlike `ecrecover`, it is impossible to get to public key given schnorr signature = (r,s) since rG = sG-eP .
So, would like to understand what are the security risks,

if we say
`signature=F(r,s,e)`

and get to publicKey at the verification? something like this
`P = (rG-sG)/e`

Comment: What is `F()` ?

Comment: I meant concatenation @PieterWuille

Answer (score 2):

There are no security risks to this since `e` is public anyway. Depending on how you are using it you probably want to make sure that `e` is consistent with R afterwards i.e. recompute `e` from `P` and `R` and `m` to make sure it is correct. However, it makes more sense to me to just include `P` directly instead of `e`.

Comment: Okay, thank you @LLFourn. But my point/question is to derive publicKey from signature.

Comment: But it's the same amount of data to just include `P`. Why can't extracting the trailing 32 bytes count as deriving?